# HAproxy path_beg not redirect

Tags: haproxy

i need use `path_beg` but seems not work, my conf file is:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    maxconn 2000
    timeout connect 600000
    timeout client 600000
    timeout server 600000

frontend http-in
    bind *:80

    acl foo     hdr(host)   -i  www.example.com
    acl bar     path_beg    /bar

    use_backend foo-cluster     if  foo
    use_backend bar-cluster     if  bar

backend foo-cluster
    balance roundrobin
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[src]
    server foo 172.51.0.201:80

backend bar-cluster
    balance roundrobin
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[src]
    server bar 172.51.0.202:80
```

backend `foo-cluster` work, if i go to `http://www.example.com/bar` i have a 404 not found from the `foo-cluster`, any ideas? (use haproxy 1.7.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 'http://www.example.com/bar' url, both foo and bar ACLs are True.
Since "use_backend foo_cluster" is evaluated first then your request will be routed to that backend even if bar ACL is True.
So you need to reorder your "use_backend" rules or be more specific in your ACLs definition.

Comment: Instead if i have same path_beg in different hostname, how can write the right acl?

Comment: In HAProxy you can overload ACLs so to make your "bar" ACL more specific you can use two criteria like this:
"acl bar     path_beg    /bar"  
"acl bar hdr(host)   -i  www.another-example.com"